# Batch output of the second and third for loop not visible

Tags: xml, batch-file, xml-parsing

I'm parsing xml and trying to write all the Well formed and valid xmls in one txt file (see string1). Another types of xmls should be written in another txt files (see string 2,3). xml files that should be analysed always has the following structure:

```
<status>Well-Formed and valid</status>
```

or

```
<status>Well-Formed, but not valid </status>
```

or

```
<status>Not well-formed  </status>
```

The problem is that I can only catch the xmls with string1. There are no output for xmls with string2 and string3 in txt file. I can't understand why?

```
 set string1=Well-Formed and valid
    set string2=Well-Formed, but not valid 
    set string3=Not well-formed  

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml\') do (
 for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%h in ('find "%string3%" %%i ') do (
echo %%~ni %%h >> C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed2.txt
)

for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%h in ('find "%string1%" %%i ') do (
 echo %%~ni %%h >> C:\Users\N\outputxml\Well-formed_and_valid.txt
 )

 for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%h in ('find "%string2%" %%i ') do (
  echo %%~ni %%h >> C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed1.txt 
 )
)
```

Comment: What do you actually want to be written to the `.txt` files? I guess it is the `Well-formatted and valid` portion, for example, right? are there any leading white-spaces in front of `<status>`? are they for sure always there? Anyway, I recommend to quote *all* file paths to avoid trouble with white-spaces or other special characters (e. g., `%%i` --> `"%%~i"`, `>> C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed2.txt` --> `>> "C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed2.txt"`). Then you should add the option string `"delims="` to the outer `for /F` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a quick alteration to your provided file to cater for the fact you were using the same **%%h** in each of the inner loops and your find command output wasn't producing your expected output.

```bat
set string1=Well-Formed and valid
set string2=Well-Formed, but not valid
set string3=Not well-formed
for %%i in (j k l) do (set %%i=0)
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir/b/s C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\outputxml') do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%j in ('find "%string3%"^<"%%i"') do (
        set/a j+=1
        >>C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed2.txt echo %%~ni %%j)
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%k in ('find "%string1%"^<"%%i"') do (
        set/a k+=1
        >>C:\Users\N\outputxml\Well-formed_and_valid.txt echo %%~ni %%k)
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=>/<" %%l in ('find "%string2%"^<"%%i"') do (
        set/a l+=1
        >>C:\Users\N\outputxml\formed1.txt echo %%~ni %%l))
echo=totals&echo=%string1%=%i%&echo=%string3%=%j%&echo=%string3%=%k%
```

See if it helps you out.

Comment: I thought that was the decision, but it doesn't help. Maybe the problem is with xml files, but they all look the same

Comment: _When you say it doesn't help, that's technically incorrect because I have fixed something_. My post was to just to cater for your obvious error, I am not willing to fix your script unless you provide a better explanation of the expected output, and what you are currently getting as output.

Comment: ok, I understand you. You really helped me with that obvious error that I didn't see. Thanks a lot!  Now I get the desired output: I've just copied "Not well-formed" and "Well-Formed, but not valid" from original XML file to the position where i declare variables. So it was all about fonts I think

Comment: This does not solve any problem, you can use the same `for` variable reference (`%%h`) for all the inner loops as its scope is limited to the respective `for` loop anyway!

Comment: Can you please help to count how many times every of these 3 "for loops" were running?  I tried to do it with count=1   count=count+1 echo !count! but it doesn't work. I need only the sum of times for every loop

Comment: added a counter for you.